# Pancake Coil Magnetic Field Strength

Tags: ac, coil, magnetic-flux, emf, field-strength

I am trying to measure the magnetic field strength of a pancake (flat) coil. I know the turns, inner radius, current, and frequency from an AC input and am trying to measure the magnetic flux so I can use faraday's law to measure EMF output in a different coil. What equation/formula would I use to measure flux/field strength.

Thanks.

Comment: Might need some more details on this coil. Is your coil a [bifilar coil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifilar_coil)? A picture would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can do it! If you have an oscilloscope you can make quite accurate magnetic field strength measurements. [Here](http://rfid-systems.at/003.pdf) is one paper, in which the procedure is explained and the properties of the probe antenna are also explained (page 4 to see the equation).

You just have to be careful which kind of probe you are using, so the cable doesn't capture power, only the loop. If you have a low frequency you can use twisted pair cable with a loop in the other end:

[image: Twisted pair cable probe]

Do be careful to make the probe small enough, if it is too close to the antenna conductors the results will not be accurate.